# Need help in Crystal reports- "field cannot be summarized"

Tags: crystal-reports

​Hi All,
I have a requirement to find standard deviation based on Actual Lead Time, Mean & Average. I have highlighted the formula fields column in the attached excel and figured out till Mean calculation. while calculating Std. Dev, i am facing error like "The field cannot be summarised".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrs1s.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Standard deviation of a record-level value, simply create a summary of type 'Population standard deviation'.

If you need to compute a standard deviation of a group-level summary, use a VIEW or Stored Procedure or Command that provides those group totals as raw data (as detail records).

Alternatively, one of the 3rd-party User Function Libraries (UFLs) listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) allows you to do totals of totals.